# JavaScript: insert an array's items inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

How to insert an array's items *inside* another array?

*Inside* means inserting the array and "expanding" it for its items to become part of the array in which they were inserted. Example:

```
var mainArr=[a,e,f,g];
var innerArr=[b,c,d];
```

with the resulting array being:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

The order of the inserted items should be retained. Assume the items are *not* sortable.

If the ExtJS framework facilitates the above via its [`Array`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Array) functions those can be utilized in this scenario.

Comment: This definition of "inside" is a little vague. It seems to mean that you want to join two arrays and then sort them in ascending order...do you mean something different?

Comment: "Inside" means inserting the array and "expanding" it for its items to become part of the array in which they were inserted. I don't want to sort them in ascending order; basically the order should be the same as that when inserted.

Comment: So instead this is finding the mid-point of one array and adding an entire array in at that point? Edit: Just seen the edit. There seems to be no consistency as to how they're merged :/

Comment: Just assume a hard-coded entry point at index `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the index to "insert" at, you can use `concat`:

```
var result = mainArr.slice(0,2).concat(innerArr, mainArr.slice(2));
```

You could also just `concat` the two arrays together and then sort them with `.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });` if they contain only numbers that are to be in order.

---

EDIT: I was not going to suggest `.splice` because it takes scalar arguments, but thanks to the magic of `.apply` you can still do it:

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(mainArr, [index,0].concat(innerArr));
```

Comment: In my code I'm using your line as `mainArr.slice(0,index).concat(innerArr, mainArr.slice(index));` where `index` is the default insertion point for the array's items. Thanks.

Comment: ohoo!! so you are answering with us. And good stuff to learn from your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert the array inside at a certain index:

```
mainArr.splice.apply(mainArr,[index,0].concat(innerArr))
```

will insert the innerArr inside the main Arr at the specified index.

This will run splice on mainArr with the arguments index,0,...innerArr contents... and add those extra arguments at the specified index.

#### Update

The one liner modifies mainArr, it doesn't return the value.

If you need to preserve mainArr, you can clone it

```
newarr = mainArr.splice(0)
newarr.splice.apply(newArr,[index,0].concat(innerArr))
```

or (less readable)

```
mainArr.splice(0).splice.apply(this,[index,0].concat(innerArr))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I tried your code but it returns an empty array: `mainArr.splice.apply(this,[index,0].concat(innerArr))` returns `[]`

Comment: yes, it modifies mainArr it doesn't create a new array.  If you need to preserve mainArr you can clone the array first and then run it on the clone.

Comment: Tried it; but `mainArr` still is not modified.

Comment: oops my mistake, wrong argument for the start of the function.  this should be newArr/mainArr.  Updated now.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, but already marked @ExplosionPills' answer as correct; +1ed yours. Thanks!

Comment: yep his answer is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
var mainArr=['a','e','f','g'];
var innerArr=['b','c','d'];
mainArr=mainArr.concat(innerArr).sort()
alert(mainArr)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fR2cC/3/

Comment: I updated my question; the components I'm using in the list are not sortable. Sorry for not making that clear immediately.